# 2d plots of 3 dimensional function in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a task to draw a potential graph with 3 variables, x , y, and z. I don't think we can draw the function U(x, y, z) directly with matplotlib. So what I'm planning to do is to draw cross sectional plots of x-y and y-z. I believe this is enough because the function U(x, y, z) has periodic behavior.

I'm quite new to python. So would you recommend or tell me where do I start or which method I can use for this?

Thank you.

Comment: you might have a look at the [contour](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html) and [contour3d](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contour3d_demo.html) functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [matplotlib scatter](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html). You can use the color and size as third and fourth variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a 3D plot with **matplotlib** and the **mplot3d toolkit**

Hope this helps : http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html